# Internal error in gold happens sporadically

Tags: gcc, gold-linker

When compiling a c++ project with protobufs in bazel with gcc, I sometimes get:

```
/usr/bin/ld.gold: internal error in try_fix_erratum_843419_optimized, at ../../gold/aarch64.cc:2114
```

The only solution appears to be to be to modify the code enough such that the resulting binaries are sufficiently different. Any clues as to what this error is, and how to avoid it?

Reducing the optimization level also seems to solve it, but I don't have full control of the build environment.